# change text upper span

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html

```
                <div class="flol pore">
                <a href="#"><span class="valdespl">Sector de Empleo</span> <i class="poab ico_arrowdesp bgindex"></i></a>
                <div class="poab despcnt dino">
                    <ul class="scroll">
                        <li><a data-value="1" href="#">Titulo de la Categoria Sector</a></li>
                        <li><a data-value="2" href="#">Titulo de la Categoria Sector</a></li>
                        <li><a data-value="3" href="#">Titulo de la Categoria Sector</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="hidden" name="sector" value="" class="inpval">
                </div>
            </div>
```

And when I want to click a link ul, changing the text of the span valdespl.

I tried several ways but I can not change it

```
$('.scroll').delegate( 'a', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('ul').prevAll('.despcnt').prev().find('span').text('hola');
});
```

Any idea?. thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.scroll').on('click', 'a', function(e) { 
    var link = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    link.closest('.flol').find('.valdespl').text('hola');
}
```

Comment: @jon90 if this worked for you (or any of these answers), please consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark the the left.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this or am i missing something?

```
 $("ul.scroll").on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("span.valdespl").html("Your text");
    });
```

Comment: Yes, it would be easy, but I'm trying to make it as a select ul, and when clicking the value stored in the hidden input. I just need to change the text in the span, but if I do as you say would have to repeat the code several times, as there are many selects on the page.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: oh i see, there is even a better way..why dont u use select element?

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to change that span, then something like this would work..

Here is a jsFiddle .. [Click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKQVX/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scroll li a').click(function(e){
    $('.valdespl').text($(this).text());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ID if you are doing an unique function coz benchmark test over id vs classes shows a big difference

Simple try using this

```
$("ul.scroll li  a").on('click',function(e){
      $(".flol a").children(".valdespl").text("hello");
 });
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XCGqN/)